# Write down interfaces for testing the Go Mongo driver

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, go

I am trying to write tests for a new project which makes use of the golang mongo driver. They sadly didn't use interfaces so I'm basically trying to write them down by myself for the few methods I'm making use of but am probably missing something with Go.

Let's say I have the following `struct` which is the root of the repository part:

```golang
type MongoChecksRunner struct {
    Client ClientHelper
}
```

`ClientHelper` is the following interface which the original `*mongo.Client` implements:

```golang
type ClientHelper interface {
    Database(name string, opts ...*options.DatabaseOptions) DatabaseHelper
    Connect(ctx context.Context) error
}
```

Every level is interfaced, so for the original `*mongo.Database` structure, we get:

```golang
type DatabaseHelper interface {
    RunCommand(ctx context.Context, runCommand interface{}, opts ...*options.RunCmdOptions) SingleResultHelper
}
```

And finally, for the original `*mongo.SingleResult` structure, we have:

```golang
type SingleResultHelper interface {
    Decode(v interface{}) error
    Err() error
}
```

However, when I try to instantiate a new `MongoChecksRunner`, it does not compile:

```golang
func NewMongoChecksRunner(host string, port int) (*MongoChecksRunner, error) {
    client, err := mdriver.NewClient(
        options.Client().ApplyURI(fmt.Sprintf("mongodb://%s:%d", host, port)),
        options.Client().SetDirect(true),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &MongoChecksRunner{
        Client: client,
    }, nil
}
```

I get the following error: `cannot use client (variable of type *mongo.Client) as ClientHelper value in struct literal: wrong type for method Database`.

Are there any limitations with Golang which prevents you from having multiple levels of nesting for interfaces ?

Please find below the original `mongo` package structures' method signatures :

```golang
func (c *Client) Database(name string, opts ...*options.DatabaseOptions) *Database
func (c *Client) Connect(ctx context.Context) error
func (db *Database) RunCommand(ctx context.Context, runCommand interface{}, opts ...*options.RunCmdOptions) *SingleResult
func (sr *SingleResult) Decode(v interface{}) error
func (sr *SingleResult) Err() error
```

Thank you in advance for any kind of help

Comment: To satisfy an interface the methods **must** match *verbatim*. `Foo() DatabaseHelper` does not match `Foo() *mongo.Database` *verbatim*, it does not matter that `*mongo.Database` implements `DatabaseHelper`, what matters is the method name and singature.

Comment: ... and therefore, to be able to do what you want, you need to write wrappers around the implementations and have those wrappers return the correct type from the interface-implementing methods.

Comment: something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53823961/965900

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helps me a lot. I find it a bit disappointing but at least I know what to do now !

Answer (score 0):

using  https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/256dpi/lungo to mock Mongo driver and have general interface